# How do I fill a rectangle with a bitmap/vector picture in the python drawSvg package?

Tags: python, fill

example:

```
d = draw.Drawing(width, height, origin=(0, 0), displayInline=False)
r = draw.Rectangle(x, y, width, height, **fill='white'**, stroke='black')
d.append(r)
```

trying to replace 'white' with way for jpg/png/bmp/svg files, doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question directly, create a `ClipPath` and append the rectangle to it. Then use `draw.Image()`, and provide the rectangular clip path you've created as a `clip_path` argument:

```
d1 = draw.Drawing(400, 400, origin=(0, 0), displayInline=False)

clipRect = draw.ClipPath()
clipRect.append(
    draw.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200, fill='white', stroke='black')
)

d1.append(
    draw.Image(
        x=0,
        y=0,
        width=400,
        height=400,
        path='https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1807/29479946208_1089e5c789_b.jpg',
        clip_path=clipRect
    )
)
```

If you just want to add an image to a drawing you can do that using:

```
d2 = draw.Drawing(400, 400, origin=(0, 0), displayInline=False)

d2.append(
    draw.Image(
        x=0,
        y=0,
        width=200,
        height=200,
        path='https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1807/29479946208_1089e5c789_b.jpg',
    )
)
```